# Can anybody explain or suggest a good reference on how to make a modular exponentiation circuit for N=15 with any coprime base?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, resource-request, shors-algorithm

I have read many papers related to it but in every paper, they just show the circuit of order finding algorithm for N=15, but did not explain what is the procedure to make it.

It will be great  if anyone who had done this can suggests a good reference or explain it here.

Thank you.